# How Do I Display A Custom Field In The Sidebar Of All My Pages?

Tags: custom-field, sidebar

I'm using the Types Plugin for Wordpress and created a custom field. I would like to display this custom field in the sidebar of all of my pages. The problem is that it only displays in the sidebar of the page I created the custom field on. It does NOT display in the sidebar on any of the other pages. Here's the code I placed in my generic sidebar.php file:

```
<?php echo(types_render_field("photo", array("alt"=>"Product image", "width"=>"300","height"=>"200","proportional"=>"true"))); ?>
```

Any ideas on how to get it to display in the sidebar of ALL the pages? I'm using the Twenty eleven theme with the latest version of Wordpress.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you just add one photo?

Comment: yes. But, this is just one example.  No matter what i use as a custom field, text box, text area, etc, it only displays in the sidebar on the page the custom field was created on.

Comment: Did you try to add "photo" on another page as well?

Comment: Yes, and then the photo will appear in the sidebar of that page, as well.  But, I don't want to have to add the photo to every page on my site to get it to appear in the sidebar.  Or maybe I'm not understanding you.  A little more info, I'm using a different page template on each page and the custom field options are specific to each page template.  Maybe that has something to do with it??

Comment: Ok, but if you want the same photo on all pages you should add a widget with a photo in it. The function you use are supposed to just show information from the current page

Comment: Typically I would use a widget, however, this site is for clients (who have no knowledge on the subject) with about 20 different themes available.  If I use widgets then when they switch themes they lose their widgets...or will have to reactivate them.  I created a sidebar page with custom fields that they can easily just fill in info or upload a photo.

Answer (score 1):

I checked the code in the repository, and this specific function doesn't have an ID parameter, meaning that it only grabs the CF of the current post/page being displayed.

A fast solution would be:

```
$my_page = get_page_by_path( 'my-page' );
$meta_values = get_post_meta($my_page->ID, 'custom-field-name', true);
```

Maybe the plugin has another function for that, but you'd better ask in the plugin support page http://wordpress.org/tags/types?forum_id=10

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I added that code to my sidebar.php file and it didn't work.  I changed 'my-page' to the page name and replaced'custom-field-name' with the custom field name and nothing appeared at all.

Comment: Hey brasofilo, I put this in my sidebar:   `<?php
    $about_page = get_page_by_title('sidebar');
    echo "$about_page->post_content";
   ?>` and I got the custom field shortcode to appear in every sidebar, but not the actual content of the custom field.  This what is appearing now: [types field="sidebartitle"][/types] But there is smart quotes which is maybe why it's displaying the short code and not the actual content?

Comment: hi, Tory, I'm not sure if this is what you need `echo do_shortcode($about_page->post_content);`. . . Did you managed to get the desired custom field content using get_post_meta?

Comment: Here's what ended up working for me: `$args=array(
  'page_id' => 39,
  'post_type' => 'page',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
);
$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
  while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
     <?php
    the_content();
  endwhile;
}
wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
?>` Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

A dirty solution:

```
$custom_image = types_render_field("photo", array("alt"=>"Product image","width"=>"300","height"=>"200","proportional"=>"true");
if($custom_image) {
    // this page has a custom photo. Print it.
    print $custom_image;
} else {
   // this page don't have a photo, therefore we output the photo of the default page
   $id = 1; // the id of the default page
   $post = get_post($id);
   setup_postdata($post);
   print types_render_field("photo", array("alt"=>"Product image","width"=>"300","height"=>"200","proportional"=>"true");
   wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Or if you really want the same photo everywhere then just use what's in the else clause

Answer (score 1):

Not sure since when, but you can pass the `post id` as an argument

```
<?php 
$postid = get_the_ID();
echo(types_render_field("photo", array("post_id"=>"$postid","alt"=>"Product image", "width"=>"300","height"=>"200","proportional"=>"true"))); 
?>
```